# Issue with get selected option and return

Tags: javascript, html

I have an issue with the return value in js. I need to return it because I wanna use it in

```
 var rusiavimas = selectedServices();
```

So, my function looks like this.

```
   function selectedServices()
    {
         var selectedServices = [];
        $('.common_change').change(function(){
        selectedServices = $(this).val();
        alert(selectedServices);
    
        
    });
        
      return selectedServices;
    
    }
```

My HTML code

```
              <select name="rusiavimas" class="common_change" id="cars">
                  <option value="none" selected disabled hidden> 
     Pasirinkite variantą 
  </option>  
          <option value="naujausi">Naujausi viršuje</option>
          <option value="pigiausi" >Pigiausi viršuje</option>
          <option value="brangiausi">Brangiausi viršuje</option>

            </select>
```

Then I select the option, in the alert function I get the correct value, but in my return, it's not returning it.

Comment: Use this `selectedServices.push($(this).val());` instead of this `selectedServices = $(this).val();`. The 2nd is overwrite the array to a single value

Comment: thank you it will return

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code contains a lot of problem, I try to fix them below

Your JS script is always return an empty array, because when you call the function `var rusiavimas = selectedServices();` the inner `.change` function is not runs and not change the value of the array

```js
var selectedServices = [];

        $('.common_change').change(function(){
            
            selectedServices.push($(this).val());
            
            if(selectedServices.length > 0){
                alert("selected service: " + selectedServices.toString());
            }
            console.log(selectedServices);
        });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="rusiavimas" class="common_change" id="cars">
        <option value="none" selected disabled hidden> 
           Pasirinkite variantą 
        </option>  
        <option value="naujausi">Naujausi viršuje</option>
        <option value="pigiausi" >Pigiausi viršuje</option>
        <option value="brangiausi">Brangiausi viršuje</option>
    </select>
```

Answer (score 1):

Each time after changing your array it gives to your array the last common value.

The best way as was said an comments use `selectedSerices.push($(this).val());`
You can also use deep copy, which is less recommended in your case `selectedSerices = [...selectedSerices, $(this).val()]`. I guess it will help you!